# Переменная с php в js

Tags: javascript, php

Необходимо передать значение переменной php в переменную JavaScript, далаю так:

```
var test = '<?=$_COOKIE["login"] ?>';
```

Но в переменную присваивается не значение переменной, а просто текст

```
<?=$_COOKIE["login"] ?>
```

Comment: В переменную нужно засунуть именно содержимое куки? Или дело в самом принципе? Если первое, то просто считайте куку через JavaScript. [Вот ссылка.](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie)

Comment: Нужно просто вывести переменную, куки это пример.

Comment: Антон, тоже выводится как текст.

Comment: в каком файле вы это делаете? в нём точно поддерживаются php-тэги? а то вдруг это .js-файл и интерпретатор ничего про него не знает

Comment: @AntonKucenko, а в чём разница? На `<?=...?>` даже short_tags уже сто лет как не влияет..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вставляете php код в html файлы, то понятно, что просто так не будет работать.
В .htaccess добавить надо:

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html .phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var test = <?=json_encode($_COOKIE["login"]) ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Неплохое дополнение, но не является ответом на вопрос, судя по описанной проблеме.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте сделать так:

1. Создаём input type="hidden" средствами PHP или в вёрстке.
2. Вставляем туда значение переменной PHP.
3. Считываем это значение в переменную JS.

Comment: Проблема в том, что я видел во многих примерах что так используют, но почему-то у меня не получается.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда Ну, ясновидящих тут нет. :) Что именно не получается? Ошибка или что-то ещё?